# Printer info removal

Tags: windows, printer, hp-officejet

I removed a printer, its icon, and anything connected to it, yet each time I log on, there is a message stating:

> C:\Program Files\HP\HP Officejet Pro 276dw MFP\bin\HP Status BL.dll
>
> The specified module could not be found.

How can I delete this message?  I've tried for a couple of days to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Removing HP printers doesn't always scrub all of the ancillary utilities.  `HP Status BL.dll` monitors ink alerts.  You're getting the message because the dll, itself, has been removed but not the service that tries to load it at startup (and now it can't find the missing module).

Open msconfig:

- click the Windows icon and type msconfig in the search box but don't hit Enter
- it will display msconfig.exe in the search window above
- right-click on msconfig.exe and select Run as administrator

I don't have that, so I can't tell you which tab will contain it (check Services and Startup).  Look for an entry called `Monitor Ink Alerts`, and uncheck that.  Then click OK to close msconfig.  The change will take effect the next time you boot up.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's in your start up items. If you're on Windows 10 or 8, open task manager (ctrl-alt-del, or ctrl-shift-esc) and go to the start up tab, and remove it.  If you're on Windows 7, it's not quite as easy, so an app that allows you to edit startup items might be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

For Win7, I followed this and it worked.
Item was located in 'Startup', in the "Manufacturer" column, it was listed as 'unknown'.
In the "Command" column, the path was as the error message was noted. 
You can leave the error message on the desktop to make sure you get the right item.
Many thanks!

Comment: You say, “I followed this”.  You followed *what?*  Are you referring to fixer1234’s answer?  Please don’t post an answer to say that another answer worked.  And, if not fixer1234’s answer, say (and link to) the source of your information, and provide the details that your answer is missing.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.